# How to prevent failure of multiple cin statements if one fails

Tags: c++, c++11

If we have multiple cin statements and one of them gets a wrong input, every following cin fails. How to prevent that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cin>>c;
    cin>>d;
    cin>>e;
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter some string for first or any other variable that expects int, every cin that follows terminates. How to prevent this failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something when it fails, wrap the above expression in an if statement.

```c++
if (!(std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e)) {
 // ...
}
```

It terminates because the stream is in a failed state. You'll have to clear the flags with `clear()` and continue parsing input.

If you want to know which input failed specifically:

```c++
int arr[] = {a, b, c, d};
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  if (!(cin >> arr[i])) {
    // ... clean up and clear() if you want to continue
  }
}
```